# How to implement a singleton per element?

Tags: javascript

**Overview**

Here is my Message Object.  I only want one object allowed per element.  The element noted in the comments.

As the user sees it, there should be only one message per element.  If the user keeps clicking a button for example I don't want to re-instantiate more messages.  Only one is needed.

One thing I could have done is disabled buttons until the message is finished being displayed...but that is just not the way I want to go.

The Effects.fade() function fades out the message after about 4 seconds.

**Question?**

How do I modify this so it only allows one instance of itself per element?

**The Object**

```
/**
 *    Message
 */

var Message = function( element ) 
{
    // need only single instance per element..so a singleton pattern per element
    this.element = element;  // This is element where the message is sent
};

Message.prototype.messages = 
{ 
    name:       'Please enter a valid name',
    email:      'Please enter a valid email',
    pass:       'Please enter passoword, 6-40 characters',
    url:        'Please enter a valid url',
    title:      'Please enter a valid title',
    tweet:      'Please enter a valid tweet',
    empty:      'Please complete all fields',
    same:       'Please make emails equal',
    taken:      'Sorry, that email is taken',
    validate:   'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:me@host.com">support</a> to reset your password',
};

Message.prototype.display = function( type ) 
{
    Control.send( this.element, this.messages[ type ] );
    var EffectsObject = new Effects( this.element );
    EffectsObject.fade( 'down', 4000);
};
```

**Use of Object**

```
this.message_object = new Message( this.response_element );
this.message_object.display( 'empty' );
```

Comment: Could you show how/where you instantiate `Message`?

Comment: Updated it again to make more readable.

Comment: Yes, you need an array to keep track of the elements.  One way of doing that is refactoring the Message class so you only instance it once, and that single instance would keep track of all elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to an existing answer, but more along the lines of the traditional concept of a singleton:

```
Message = function(element) {
    if (element.hasOwnProperty("messageInstance")) {
        return element.messageInstance;
    }

    element.messageInstance = this;

    // Remainder of your constructor logic here
};
```

This way you don't have to keep track of all your tagged elements in a centralized location, and you can call `new Message(element)` as many times as you like and be certain you'll only ever get back a single instance.

**EDIT**: `setAttribute` is a method on `Element` specifically for dealing with attributes of DOM nodes (i.e. the things like `href` on an `<a>` tag or `id` on, well, pretty much anything).

By comparison, the dot notation, or equivalently bracket notation (`element['messageInstance']`) sets properties on any arbitrary JavaScript object. Either approach will work, but since *messageInstance* is not technically a legal attribute according  to ([X](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/xhtml11_schema.html))[HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html) specs, assigning it as an object property is technically more correct.

Comment: Why don't you use setAttribute?...the example below uses setAttribute instead of adding the property using the . operator.

Comment: The answer is a little wordy for a comment -- addressed in the answer body above :)

Comment: But what unsets the property when it is complete?

Comment: You can do `delete element.messageInstance` to remove the property afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

or you can add a custom attribute to the element, then oncreate a new Message instance,, check if there is the custom attribute

```
Message = function( element ) 
{
    if ( !element.getAttribute("messageInstance")  ){
        // need only single instance per element..so a singleton pattern per element
        this.element = element;  // This is element where the message is sent
        element.setAttribute("messageInstance" , "true");
    } else {
        throw new Error ( "one elem one instance");
    }
};
```

Comment: Question:  Why do I need to use setAttribute...the example above just adds an attribute directly using the . operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the constructor in a closure.

```
(function () {
    var messageInstances = {};

    Message = function(element) {
        if (messageInstances[element.name])
            return messageInstances[element.name];

        this.element = element;

        messageInstances[element.name] = this;
    }

    Message.prototype.messages = {...};
    Message.prototype.display = {...};

})();
```

The `Message` identifier is defined inside a closure, but without the `var` keyword, so it is accessible globally. The `messageInstances` is a "private" (not accessible outside the closure) array that keeps track about existing instances. If a `Message(element)` constructor is called for the first time for a given `element`, a new object is created. If it is called again, the previously created instance will be found in the array and returned instead of a newly created object.

Note that in this example, elements must be discerned by some string property, like a `name`.

Comment: This is off topic..but make note to create privacy you have to run an anonymous function...i.e. this is done at run-time...I've always found this interesting that privacy requires run-time resources.